# Tracking entry views by logged in member

Tags: statistics

I've looked through the questions and responses here in EESE and I've looked at the couple of add-ons that were mentioned. Tracker by Solspace seems close to what I want, but but not quite.

I'm looking to track views of entries - but not just raw numbers as the native entry tracking will allow.  I would like to track, at an entry level, which logged-in members have viewed a given entry.  Then create a reports template that displays this information.  So essentially I want to capture the member ID of the logged in user whenever a specific entry from a given channel is loaded.  Is that possible?

I thought of having each link to a single entry template in fact be a channel form submission of entry ID and member ID.  But that may be more work than it's worth if there is already a simpler way to achieve this. And it doesn't help me with pages that contain multiple entries (list-view templates).  This is a site that is entirely member based

I would appreciate any advice the community can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use or extend the 'Recently Viewed' module to achieve your objective. :)

https://github.com/ninefour/recently_viewed.mod.ee_addon

The "Recently Viewed Entries" module allows you to keep a record of recently viewed entries on a per member basis and display that data back to the user in your page templates. The module uses the members session ID so they need not be logged in.

Comment: Hmm. Gets me partway there, I would guess. But I'm not looking to display the info to the user. I'm looking to display it to an admin, so I can't rely on session data. I'd have to store it in a table.  Is that something it might be able to do? Rather than by session ID, store the logged in member's ID and the ID of the entries they visited?  It does seem close!

Comment: Hi Jean, yes that add-on stores the data in a DB table; session_id, channel_id and entry_id. You could then either create a 'admin only' template to output that data or use a reporting module though I'm not sure there are any available for EE2.x, I wrote one for EE1.x (https://github.com/ninefour/reports.mod.ee_addon) which one day I will no doubt migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Jean,

This is something that can be accomplished with a custom built module. You would need both the functionality to record the views and also the tags to display them in your report template. It actually wouldn't be terribly complicated to do.